# Why deleting copy constructor affects user-defined default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, destructor

Learning C++, have few question regarding constructors.

Please consider following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

// Case 1

class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo()  { printf("CFoo constructor: user-defined default\n"); }
    ~CFoo() { printf("CFoo destructor\n"); }
};

void testFoo()
{
    CFoo foo0;              // A way to use default constructor
    CFoo foo1 = CFoo();     // Another way to use default constructor
    CFoo foo2 = CFoo(foo1); // Using implicit copy constructor

    // Output:
    //     CFoo constructor: user-defined default
    //     CFoo constructor: user-defined default
    //     CFoo destructor
    //     CFoo destructor
    //     CFoo destructor
    //     CFoo destructor
}

// Case 2

class CBar
{
public:
    CBar() { printf("CBar constructor: user-defined default\n"); }
    CBar(CBar & other) = delete;
    ~CBar() { printf("CBar destructor\n"); }
};

void testBar()
{
    CBar bar0;
    // line 44: error C2280: 'CBar::CBar(CBar &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
    // line 34: note: see declaration of 'CBar::CBar'
    // line 34: note: 'CBar::CBar(CBar &)' : function was explicitly deleted
    // CBar bar1 = CBar(); // Why this has anything to do with the copy constructor?

    // Output:
    //     CBar constructor: user-defined default
    //     CBar destructor
}

// Case 3

class CBaz
{
public:
    CBaz()             { printf("CBaz constructor: user-defined default\n"); }
    CBaz(CBaz & other) { printf("CBaz constructor: user-defined copy\n"); }
    ~CBaz()            { printf("CBaz destructor\n"); }
};

void testBaz()
{
    CBaz baz0;
    CBaz baz1 = CBaz();
    CBaz baz2 = CBaz(baz1);

    // Output:
    //     CBaz constructor: user-defined default
    //     CBaz constructor: user-defined default
    //     CBaz constructor: user-defined copy
    //     CBaz destructor
    //     CBaz destructor
    //     CBaz destructor
}

// main

void main() {
    testFoo();
    testBar();
    testBaz();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Questions:

1. Why I can't create an instance of `CBar` as `CBar bar1 = CBar();` as I did with `CFoo`?
2. `testFoo` invokes 4 destructors. 3 of them are for foo0, foo1 and foo2. Where does 4th come from? `testBaz` has the same structure, but only invokes 3 destructors. The only difference between `CFoo` and `CBaz` is that `CBaz` has user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: `CBar bar1 = CBar();` is not a assignation, but an initialization using copy/move constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why I can't create an instance of `CBar` as `CBar bar1 = CBar();` as I did with `CFoo`?

The copy constructor of `CBar` is deleted. Therefore `CBar` is not copyable. Therefore you cannot copy initialize a `CBar`.

`CFoo` is copyable, so there is no problem.

> ```
> CBar bar1 = CBar(); // Why this has anything to do with the copy constructor?
> ```

`T object = other;` is syntax for copy initialization.

---

> 2. Where does 4th come from?

Besides the named objects (variables), there are two temporary objects constructed, `CFoo()` and `CFoo(foo1)`. For whatever reason, only one of those temporaries was optimized away with copy elision.

> `testBaz` has the same structure, but only invokes 3 destructors.

This somehow affected the opimizer. I see no reason why both CFoo` temporaries couldn't have been optimized away as well, but one wasn't. For what it's worth, my compiler did optimize both.

---

PS. `CBaz baz1 = CBaz();` is ill-formed because non-const lvalue references cannot bind to temporaries.

PPS. `void main()` is ill-formed because `main` must return `int`

Comment: Could you elaborate why `CBaz baz1 = CBaz();` is ill-formed please?

Comment: @AlexXsWx `CBaz()` is a temporary. The argument of the copy constructor is of type `CBaz &`. It may not be bound to a temporary. Since a copy constructor should not modify its argument, you should use `const CBaz &` as the argument. Const references may bind to temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

`CBar bar1 = CBar();` is not a assignation, but an initialization using copy/move constructor.

Even if elided, the move/copy constructor should be accessible.

Since C++17, with guarantied elision, rules has changed, and 
`CBar bar1 = CBar();` doesn't require that move/copy constructor be accessible,
 and it would be equivalent to `CBar bar1{};`.

Answer (score 1):

This is direct initialization:

```
CFoo foo0;
```

This is copy initialization:

```
CBaz baz1 = CBaz();
```

Due to [*copy elision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), copy initialization becomes equivalent to direct initialization in terms of performance, but not in semantics; copy initialization still requires an accessible copy constructor.

Two of the four destructor printouts come from instances constructed with the default copy constructor of `CFoo`. Note that the number of printouts depends on optimization: when copy elision optimization is on, the call of copy constructor for the middle case, i.e. `CFoo foo1 = CFoo()` can be optimized out, so you get three printouts, not four. A copy on the right side of `CFoo foo2 = CFoo(foo0)` is not optimized out.